# Difference between Azure SQL Virtual Machine version and SQL Server Database version

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, virtual-machine

Hi sorry if this question is confusing I have just recently upgraded one of the SQL datbases to Version 15 (which is SQL 2019) inside my SQL Virtual Machine. It is a different version from my Azure SQL Virtual Machine which is SQL server version 2016. I am wondering what the pros and cons of this are and if I should be worried at all about any problems. 
[Upgrade 2019 SQL DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORnwa.png)
[Azure SQL VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wII2V.jpg)

edit: I updated the database to 2019 and it is not showing on sql server configuration manager SQL Services. I can see the database protocols (TCP), I can see the service through Windows Services, but it just does not show on SQL Services. 
I need that for moving my master.mdf file. I am wondering what the solutions to this would be is downgrading the version from 2019 back to 2016 a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you upgrade your SQL Server in your VM to 2019, or in case it does not work, because of an incorrect upgrade to 2019 of your database, you can get your original 2016 version of your database, and run the [Data Experimentation Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dea/database-experimentation-assistant-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) to assess the upgrade to 2019 and see if there are any issues with the upgrade.